# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: api, flutter, dart, jwt

Hi I have an issue with Flutter.
I get this Exception:

Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

I try to check if token exists from a response.

```
    var res = await ApiService().postData(loginData, 'login');
var body = json.decode(res.body);
if (json.decode(res.body)['token']) {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  localStorage.setString('token', body['token']);
  localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(body['user']));
  Navigator.push(
      context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserHome()));
} else {
  print(body['message']);
}
```

Comment: on which line do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change this condition

```
if (json.decode(res.body)['token'])
```

to

```
if (body['token']?.isNotEmpty == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your condition.

```
if (json.decode(res.body)['token'] != null)
```

Since i assume token is not a bool type.